# Splitting answers and counting (and visualizing) the responses

Tags: r, tidyverse, survey, microsoft-forms

I have responses coming from Microsoft Forms where people had a multiple choice option. It is part of a larger data frame and one ofc the columns with the responses coming from my CSV looks like the following:

| Which method of transport do you use? |
| --- |
| own car; bicycle |
| own car |
| own car; bicycle; public transport |
| public transport; something other that people where able to put in themselves |
| ... |

Now I would like to visualize this and count the responses. The ranking is not relevant (there was no option to click bicycle 1st place and so on).

I started with a simple

```
question1 <- df %>% strsplit(`Which method of transport do you use?`, ";")
```

That gave me a list, but I am not sure it is the right start and not sure how to move on from here to make some nice graphs and show the answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

data %>%  
  separate_rows(transport, sep = "; ") %>%  
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x = transport) + 
  geom_bar()
```

Data:

```
structure(list(transport = c("own car; bicycle", "own car", "own car; bicycle; public transport", 
"public transport; something other")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. I edited my example above, so it becomes clearer.

Comment: @QuestJonas Which part exactly "doesn't work"? Nothing seems to be any clearer in your example. Using `separate_rows` as suggested here is a much better idea that using `strsplit`

Comment: It says: 
Error in UseMethod("separate_rows") : 
no applicable method for 'separate_rows' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: @QuestJonas is your data in a dataframe or even a structure like from `Hoel`'s example?

Comment: @QuestJonas Update your question with a `dput(your dataframe)`

Comment: I must apologize to all of you, it works now. Thank you for all of your suggestions!